# Convert 2d-array storing BINARY TREE information into JSON type string

Tags: c++, json, c++11, binary-tree

I have a 2d-array storing information about a binary tree as shown below:
[image: table]

And I want to convert it into the below format:

```
{
   "id_":1,
   "leftChild_":{
      "id_":2,
      "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_LEAF",
      "size_":50
   },
   "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_NODE",
   "rightChild_":{
      "id_":3,
      "leftChild_":{
         "id_":4,
         "leftChild_":{
            "id_":6,
            "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_LEAF",
            "size_":48
         },
         "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_NODE",
         "rightChild_":{
            "id_":7,
            "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_LEAF",
            "size_":6
         },
         "size_":54
      },
      "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_NODE",
      "rightChild_":{
         "id_":5,
         "nodeType_":"CLASSIFICATION_LEAF",
         "size_":46
      },
      "size_":100
   },
   "size_":150
}
```

I've been able to do it using recursion.
But I have to do it iteratively (preferably a bottom up approach)

So how can I implement it in C++ without using any external libraries?

Comment: I would suggest using `boost::property_tree::read_json` and not storing binary trees in 2d arrays

Comment: I'm working on a project that doesn't allow us to do this. Please indicate if you have a solution to this specific problem.

Comment: your project disallows to change data type or to use boost?

Comment: I'm being given data as a 2d-array (which i cannot change) and also i can't use any external libraries.